# Can't Plot Loss and Accuracy After training datasets

Tags: python, pytorch

I already training my dataset with this code before

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs):
since = time.time()
#device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
best_acc = 0.0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  
        
    print('Epoch {}/{} LR {:.6f}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1, scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]))
    print('-' * 10)

    # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
    for phase in ['train', 'validation']:
        if phase == 'train':
            model.train()  # Set model to training mode
        else:
            model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

        #print(model.train())
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0

        # Iterate over data.
        for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            #print(inputs)
            #print(labels)
            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward
            # track history if only in train
            with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                if phase == 'train':
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()

            # statistics
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
        if phase == 'train':
            scheduler.step()

        epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
        epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]
        print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
            phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

        # deep copy the model
        if phase == 'validation' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
            best_acc = epoch_acc
            best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

    print()

time_elapsed = time.time() - since
print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
    time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

# load best model weights
model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
return model


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

#decay LR(Learning Rate) by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model = train_model(model,criterion, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=5).to(device)
```

and after I training my dataset I want to plot the result of loss and accuracy from my training. I train my dataset with VGG16 architecture. and I'm using Dataset Caltech101 which is amount thousand of images

```
ss_values = []
loss_values.append(model['train','validation'])
plt.plot(loss_values)
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

but it can't plotting my loss and accuracy result. and I don't know why

Comment: Where do the fields of `train` and `validation` come from in your model? Does the VGG model innately track losses?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem. I couldn't plot the result before because I was not putting the result into the tensorboard. Now I can plot the result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).